# Script to reorder ACLs in Windows server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, access-control-list

I have ran a tool called admnalow.exe that re-grants access to the local administrators (BUILTIN\Administrators) group for all directories and subdirectories in a given path.  The problem is it seems to have caused the ACL's to be ordered improperly.  I've been looking everywhere and have been unable to find a .vbs or any other script that will parse through a set of directories and reorder the ACLs.  This can be done manually but would be incomprehensible for thousands of directories.

Can anyone help?!?!

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `icacls` command with the `/verify` argument will do what you're looking for. Add the `/T` argument to make it apply to files and subdirectories.